# c++ template with "infinite" arguments

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

so i have this struct:

```
template <typename T>
struct _vect2 {
    T x;
    T y;
    _vect2(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) { }
    _vect2() { }
};
```

And i want to create a function that takes an "infinite" amount of those structs.

```
template <typename T, _vect2<T>... Args>
double vect_distance(Args... arguments) {}
```

How it should work:

```
struct vect_2i : public _vect2<int> {
    vect_2i() : _vect2() { }
    vect_2i(int x, int y) : _vect2(x, y) { }
};

vect_2i vect1, vect2;
auto distance = vect_distance(vect1, vect2);
```

With this code i get a syntax error and i don't know why. What is the correct way to take the arguments?

Comment: How could you ever pass infinite structs?

Comment: Do you mean *arbitrary* number of structs?

Comment: And is the error a secret?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up types and non-types...

Comment: yes @cigien, i just looked up but i didnt see any 'ways' to do it with a struct that takes another template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deduce the first argument's type, and force others to derive from/be a vector of the same deduced `T` type.

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
#include <concepts>
template <typename T>
double vect_distance(const vect2<T>& head,
                     const std::derived_from<vect2<T>> auto&... tail);
```

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto vect_distance(const vect2<T>& head, const Ts&... tail)
    -> std::enable_if_t<(std::is_base_of<vect2<T>, Ts>{} && ...), double>;
```

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
#include <type_traits>
template <bool...>
struct bool_pack {};    
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
auto vect_distance(const vect2<T>& head, const Ts&... tail)
    -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<bool_pack<true, std::is_base_of<vect2<T>, Ts>{}...>,
                                     bool_pack<std::is_base_of<vect2<T>, Ts>{}..., true>
                                     >{}, double>;
```